# SharedPreference - clearing and readding

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have a few data I saved in SharedPreference. WHen a button is clicked, the user is logged out and the sharedPreference is cleared by calling pref.clear() ad pref.commit(). When a user tries to log back in, the editor is called to commit() but it wouldn't save the new values. Any suggestions why shared preference is not saving after clearing is done?

Clearing part:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
                               SharedPreferences.Editor sa = prefs.edit();
                               sa.clear();
                               sa.commit();
```

re-adding part:

```
editor.putString("bucket", bucket);
            editor.putString("profileid", profileid);
            editor.putString("username", user);
            editor.putString("password", pass);
            editor.commit();
```

**CLOSED**: answer in the bottom but for anyone else that is looking for an answer, i accepted the answer

Comment: what is `editor`? I know it's `SharedPreferences.Editor` but just for confirmation post your code where you have declared `editor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are you initializing editor (whitch I asume is SharedPreferences.Editor). I use the following to get editor.

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("a_string", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
```

I do this the same way for clearing and saving my data.

pleas post more information if this dose not help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my fault, there was a typo while I was initiation my preferences. Sorry folks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a working example of how to add/read/remove data from `SharedPeferences`.In your `Activity` for adding some data into `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("yourPrefName",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("bucket", bucket);
editor.putString("profileid", profileid);
editor.putString("username", user);
editor.putString("password", pass);
editor.commit();
```

You would want to do the above when is user is logged in successfully.Now when the user logout, inside your `onClickListener` for logout `Button`

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("yourPrefName",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

So in your `Activity`'s code you should check if `SharedPreferences` values are already set.If they are set, then you can redirect user to the home screen without having to login again.